# How to install Apt package without starting systemd process?

Tags: systemd

How can I install an Apt package, and prevent its systemd process from starting?

A similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74061/install-packages-without-starting-background-processes-and-services) was asked and answered years ago, except for SysV instead of systemd.

(Installing the package, and stopping its systemd service isn't a good enough solution.)

Comment: The right answer _would_ be systemd presets, were they widely employed by Debian/Ubuntu packagers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by running only the unpack part of the installation

```
 apt-get download <package>
 sudo dpkg --unpack <package>*.deb
```

You could then edit the packages systemd config so it cannot be started

So you dont avoid other parts of the setup you will need to finish it by running

```
sudo dpkg --configure <package>
```

This might error when it tries to start the systems service depending on how you disabled it and how the service works.